# Trouble getting listener to listen to database changes for one of my tables

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase, I'm having trouble getting my listener working, which listens to database changes for one of my collections.

Code example:

```
this.refAdminNotifications.on('value', (dataSnapshot) => {
  console.log("Listening to changes - change occurred in db");
});
```

languages I'm using: Angular 2, TypeScript and Firebase. Problem is the listeners not being called.

This is my firebase version: https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: its not hitting the console log

Comment: This will not solve the problem but just a suggestion to use arrowfunction  like `this.refAdminNotifications.on('child_changed', (dataSnapshot)=> {
          console.log("Listening to changes - change occured in db");
        });`

Comment: @micronyks have you ever got a listener working?

Comment: Yes, but I'm unable to say anything on AngularFirebase. I don't use it.

Comment: @micronyks i dont use AngularFirebase either. I use just basic firebase. This is library im using: https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js

Comment: [Attaching an error listener](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/23610/detecting-errors-when-reading-data-in-javascript#t=201610021535086215054) may tell you what's going wrong. Any reason why you're not using the latest 3.x version of the Firebase SDK?

Comment: Can you share how you are setting `this.refAdminNotifications`? And maybe a snapshot of the Firebase console of the data you are trying to detect changes, so we can see the structure of your database? It'll make it really easy for us to help you then. Thanks!

Comment: Got it working, I moved the listener to the app.ts file for now